# On Matlab while running this code I am getting this error, Z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector

Tags: matlab

I am unable to generate mesh or surf while using this code

`z must be a matrix, not a scalar or vector`

```
r= 5;
theta= 60 ;
ro=5;
w1=200;
w2=300;
t=0:1:60;
dt=diff(t);
x=ro*cos(w1.*t)+r.*cos(theta+(w1+w2).*t)
dx=diff(x);
y=ro*sin(w1.*t)+r.*sin(theta+(w1+w2).*t)
dy=diff(y);
a=(dx./dt).^2;
b=(dy./dt).^2;
v=sqrt(a+b);
[x,y]=meshgrid(x,y);
surf(x,y,v)
```

Answer (score 1):

v is a vector. from Matlab's documentation:

> The function plots the values in matrix Z as heights above a grid in the x-y plane defined by X and Y

I.e v should be a matrix (in the size of length(x) * length(y)).
Usually, the meshgrid output itself could be passed for the calculations on each of the 2D locations :

> [X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
> Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
> surf(X,Y,Z)

see: [surf docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/surf.html)